# Why my Yarn shows less memory (12 GB) than host machine (32) GB

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I am using EMR and I have task nodes with 32 GB of memory. However when I login to my  YARN UI. it says it has only 12 GB of memoery.

Yes, I understand some memory should be used by OS and other services running. However, 20 GB is too much.

[image]

**On host machine**

```
free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           30G        18G        12G        88K       128M        12G
-/+ buffers/cache:       5.6G        25G
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

on other machine.

```
 free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           30G        11G        18G        88K        75M       8.5G
-/+ buffers/cache:       3.4G        27G
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

so even after having 18 gb free, why Yarn shows only 12 GB available?

Comment: I'm not familiar with EMR, but check your `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` setting. That's the setting that controls how much memory is allocated to the nodemanager

Answer (score 0):

After doing some search on google that it was being restricted by yarn setting. Same thing has been suggested by pradeep in his comment.

I did the following thing the setting on the cluster

1. Find out the instance group ID for your task and core nodes. Use following command for that.

```
aws emr describe-cluster --cluster-id j-xxxxxx | jq -r '.Cluster.InstanceGroups[] | select(.InstanceGroupType == "CORE").Id'
aws emr describe-cluster --cluster-id j-xxxxxx | jq -r '.Cluster.InstanceGroups[] | select(.InstanceGroupType == "TASK").Id'
```

2. Create JSON configuration to update your emr. You will have to create two configuration file one for TASK group and another for Core group. Or you can simple replace value of `InstanceGroupId` after each update.

```
[
   {
      "InstanceGroupId":"<output_of_above_command>",
      "Configurations":[
         {
            "Classification":"yarn-site",
            "Properties":{
               "yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb":"32768"
            },
            "Configurations":[]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

3. Finally run the command to update the instance group.

```
aws emr modify-instance-groups --cluster-id j-******* --instance-groups file://instaceGroup.json
```